# detect up/down and tab keys press in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I detect if the `up/down/left/right` or the `tab` key is pressed, I tried to use the code below but it doesn't print something when those keys are pressed

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
    console.log(e.key)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `keydown` instead of `keypress`

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    console.log(e.keyCode)
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        console.log("up arrow")// up arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        console.log("down arrow")// down arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '9') {
       console.log("tab")// tab
    }
 

}
```